# Firestore: Storing user comments in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine you have a “Posts” model in firestore which has image, description, rating, comments etc. You want to display 10 or 15 comments when the post is clicked by user. Question is:
Would you store comments in “Posts” model as a field or would you create another new data model “Comments” for that?
In the first situation i wonder how to handle if the post has 1.000.000 comments? you can’t paginate a field as far as i know. Each time you need to fetch all of the comments and its kinda heavy and useless request i think. What is the best way to store comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have answered your question yourself :)

I would create an another data model / table so you can easier implement:

- pagination
- remove / edit
- likes
- answers to comments etc...

this brings more complexity, but is a more elegant and flexible solution.

The first solution only makes sense if it can't happen that there are 1 million comments. For example in an intranet application. But better not do it, because the effort is actually the same.

Comment: i was considering saving directly inside document than create a document for each comment, to save on the amount of read i do

Answer (score 2):

> Would you store comments in “Posts” model as a field or would you create another new data model “Comments” for that? In the first situation i wonder how to handle if the post has 1.000.000 comments?

There is no "100% correct" way of doing this, but your modeling should match the requirements of your expected use case.  Without knowing how you are going to query this data, you might make a bad design decision.

Note that the maximum size of a Firestore document is 1MB.  If you are expecting a large number of posts, then that simply will not fit inside a single document, and you should instead store each post as a separate document in a subcollection.

If you need to paginate any items at all, you should always store them as separate documents.  Firestore queries can't fetch partial documents - a read always gets everything in the document.